# Wifi not working after installing updates on 12.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, updates, samsung

Yesterday, I've installed Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS (using Windows installer WUBI) on my Samsung NP300E4Z-A06IN laptop.

At first everything was fine. But it showed that there were some updates available(around 306MB). After installing the updates, its not connecting to wifi. I tried to connect but won't succeed.

Please help me out. I am new in the world of Linux.

Comment: We are interested to know more the details.. I mean, the type of your network card. Just in case that you are using the broadcom network adapter, there are chances that you might need to reInstall the driver via the LAN cable connection (you can't use the WiFi right?) I hope this might help, and please do correct and inform me if I'm mistaken. Thanks, and peace...

Comment: I am able to use internet on Ubuntu Desktop from mobile phone using bluetooth. Anyway we just needed to reinstall the drivers right?

Answer (score 0):

Install NDISWrapper and NDISgtk in the Software Center and try installing the official Windows driver that way.

Comment: "try installing the official Windows driver " means?

Comment: yes, NDISwrapper can be used to install the windows driver related to the networking drivers (old guys, correct me if I'm mistaken). To be exact, not the driver installer but the drivers (how should I put it in words.. huh..?) which are the dlls files and stuffs.

Comment: But at first it worked fine with Ubuntu desktp 12.04 LTS. But it went wrong after installing updates:(